# Show tooltip only on a specific css class with jquery

Tags: jquery, css, tooltip

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("[title]:not(.ItemImage)").removeAttr('title');
});
```

This removes the tooltip of anything else but it not remove the default tooltip from my specific class (.ItemImage).

Comment: maybe using `:not`? like `$("[title]:not(.myClass)")`?

Comment: The title of "a.ItemImage" is what I want to show in tooltip. Nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

You can custom Class right.

difine two set of class..so that you can disable the set

Answer (score 0):

are you mean this ?

```
$('a.have_tt').attr('title',$(this).data('title'));
```

Comment: I'm talking about this:

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("[title]:not(.ItemImage)").removeAttr('title');
});

But removing the default tooltip from the .ItemImage class and leaving the custom via css:

a.ItemImage[title]:hover:after {}